# Azure Storage Account vs Storage as a resource in RG

Tags: azure, storage, account

I want to know what is the difference between Azure Storage account and storage as a resource in a resource group. Besides my main Azure account, do I need to create another user account for storage subscription? Or I can just take storage as a resource in one of my subscriptions? I saw this while managing MS SQL Server Backup to MS Azure Tool GUI 
[image]

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `storage as a resource in a resource group`. Can you please elaborate that?

Comment: In azure we take resources right and group then in RGs under Azure account subscription? Can't  storage be considered a resource? @GauravMantri

Comment: A Storage account is not a user account. It's what they call each Storage instance that you create.

Comment: The `storage account` is just the name of the azure resource, it is not a really account like your user account. So in your case, just use your user account to create the resource `storage account` in your subscription.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create another user account for storage subscription.

Just create an azure storage account as per this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-quickstart-create-account?tabs=azure-portal) in your current subscription.